# Custom datatypes in SML

Tags: types, enums, sml

I'm playing around with datatypes in SML for the first time. I've defined a datatype called suit with the four suits of playing cards

```
datatype suit = Spades | Clubs | Hearts | Diamonds;
```

Now I want to write a function that takes a suit and returns a string representation of it. Here it is currently

```
fun suitname(x) =
if x = Spades then
    "Spades"
else if x = Clubs then
    "Clubs"
else if x = Diamonds then
    "Diamonds"
else if x = Hearts then
    "Hearts"
else
    "Undefined suit";
```

It compiles fine but when I try to call it with each suit

```
suitname Hearts;
suitname Spades;
suitname Clubs;
suitname Diamonds;
```

I get this error

[image]

and have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: You can shorten the if-else chain to `case x of Spades => "Spades" | Clubs => "Clubs" | Diamonds => "Diamonds" | Hearts => "Hearts"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message looks like you defined the datatype `suit` twice (perhaps interactively?), and the definition of the function is using the older definition, and the call sites the newer. Try to reenter the function definition.

Comment: I see what happened, I defined the datatype after I defined the function. Apparently definition order matters in this language. This answer made me realize that so I'll accept it. Thanks